# Unprojecting 2D screen coordinates to 3D world coordinates

Tags: java, 3d, 2d, projection

I'm doing some projecting and after projecting to 2D I want to the reverse operation, unprojecting to 3D. The only step I am confused at is when going from NDC to HDC, more specific how to do reverse of the perspective division? Currently when doing the reverse I end up with a -1 w-value which isn't going to do much when dividing or multiplying, or maybe there is something else I am overseeing. This is the code I currently have:

```
    private Vector3f projectTo3D(Matrix4f projection, Matrix4f view, Matrix4f world, Vector3f vertex) {

    Matrix4f.invert(projection, projection);
    Matrix4f.invert(view, view);
    Matrix4f.invert(world, world);

    System.out.println("projectTo3D - Screen Coordinate: " + vertex.toString());

    ....

    System.out.println("NDC: " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z);
    final Vector4f HDC = new Vector4f(x, y, z, -1f);
    HDC.x = HDC.x / HDC.w;
    HDC.y = HDC.y / HDC.w;
    HDC.z = HDC.z / HDC.w;

    System.out.println("HDC before transform: " + HDC.toString());
    Matrix4f.transform(worldProjectionView, HDC, HDC);
    System.out.println("HDC after transform: " + HDC.toString());

    final Vector3f worldCoordinates = new Vector3f(HDC.x, HDC.y, HDC.z);
    System.out.println("World coordinate: " + worldCoordinates.toString());
    return worldCoordinates;
}
```

> ---
>
> projectTo2D - World Coordinate: Vector3f[-50.0, -50.0, 0.0]
>
> HDC: Vector4f: -195.05373 -44.30973 -529.6105 -529.6105
>
> NDC: Vector3f[0.3682966, 0.08366475, 0.0]
>
> ### Screen coordinate: 547.31866, 325.09943, 0.0
>
> ---
>
> projectTo3D - Screen Coordinate: Vector3f[**547.31866, 325.09943, 0.0**]
>
> NDC: 0.36829662, 0.083664775, -1.0
>
> HDC before transform: Vector4f: -0.36829662 -0.083664775 1.0 -1.0
>
> HDC after transform: Vector4f: -292.38623 405.26837 -291.50772 1.0
>
> ### World coordinate: Vector3f[-292.38623, 405.26837, -291.50772]

I am following this diagram:

[image]

Comment: You can't unambiguously - you are trying to make 3 numbers from 2 numbers - that is impossible because it is creating information. You can only project from a point in 2d space to a line in 3d space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this myself. My mistake was setting the near plane of the projection matrix to 0 and this should be minimum 0.1

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a linear algebra problem here, and one which is unfortunately unsolvable. When you project a 3D-coordinate space onto a 2D space, which is the job of the model->viewport transform, you're losing a dimension along the way, and the reverse problem becomes under-constrained.

What I mean by that is, if you only have a vector in a 2D space (such as a point in a screen), there is an infinite number of 3D vectors which could project onto the same 2D vector, forming a new 1D vector space. And since the projection is not an affine (linear) operation, this means your 1D space is not a straight line; rather, a curved line in 3D space.

Comment: So there is no way to unproject a point from 2D to 3D even if you preserve the z-value given from the projectTo2D function?

Comment: If, and **only if**, you preserve the Z coordinate from the original 3D point/vector, then it's possible, and it actually becomes trivial: you just project the point using your same projection algorithm. You have the X and Y coordinates from your previous step, plug in your own Z, pass it through your projection code, and it's done!

Comment: I am aware of that, I project the 3D coordinate `-50, -50, 0` to 2D and try to unproject it again but as declared in the OP the values I'm getting are: `-292.38623, 405.26837, -291.50772` instead of `-50, -50, 0`